# How do I store versions of model data in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, version, versioning

I want to implement a way to version models in a ruby on rails app. (version 3.1+). What I am after is much like what mediawiki does; making it easy to diff the changes made, showing what changed and who changed it. Also, I would like to be able to store associated models (imagine comments on a blogpost). However, this last feature is a should-have, not a dealbreaker.

I should also be able to revert to older version of the model's data, not losing the versions that came after it.

I already ran into PaperTrail:
https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Are there (better) alternatives? I am also not sure if paper trail allows for diffs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not take a look at the [Ruby Toolbox / Versioning](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Versioning)

In my opinion the only options are:

- Paper Trail
- Vestal versions

all other are rather inactive.

As for diffing: Paper Trail can definitely do diffing of versions see https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail and look for 'Diffing Versions'

Comment: Thanks, I watched this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail , along with you pointing out the 'diffing versions' (which I neglected to see), this is just the answer I was looking for.